# Hide all items untill filter is selected jQuery isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I would like to hide all items until filter is selected. I can't figure out from the documentation if there's an option for that and how to configure it.

For example
I have filters:

```
Shirts | Pants | Shoes (filters)

---------------------- (grid with items that need to be filtered)
Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3
...    | ...    | ...
...    | ...    | ...
...    | ...    | ...
----------------------
```

How can I make all items be hidden until first filter is selected?

Thanks!

I'm using jQuery isotope plugin for that.

Comment: Why don't you go with PHP & MySQL ? Easy: Got a table on the database, filter whatever you like with a query.

I see you need specific help for jQuery, but if you reproduce your tables on a SQL database and print them through PHP you will definitely save time and reduce difficulties.

Hope this was at least a bit helpful since nobody answered, bye !

Of course there is a way throughout jQuery and javascript, you could try to save all your items into arrays, then filter this arrays and print what you need through a printer function. If you want me to do it, I can write down the whole script..

Comment: @FoxNos It should be animated, and I'm working on someone else joomla component and don't have time to write that stuff my self.

Comment: Well, in this case you could go with AJAX, PHP, and MySQL.. I will try to provide some code anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html#jquery_script):

> To show only .metal items, the jQuery script would be:
>
> $('#container').isotope({ filter: '.metal' });

My first idea to hide all items was setting the `filter` option to an empty string, but it did not work. However, if you set it to some non-existing class, then all items will be hidden:

```
$('#container').isotope({ filter: '.dummy' });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MErWJ/) is the jsfiddle.

---

*Comments of @RizkySyaiful:*

Also, if you this a code snippet http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JGKyrY (made by the creator of Isotope), you can just simply change this line

```
// combine inclusive filters
var filterValue = inclusives.length ? inclusives.join(', ') : '*';
```

to

```
// combine inclusive filters
var filterValue = inclusives.length ? inclusives.join(', ') : '.dummy';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
$('.filter').click(function(){
    var type = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $('article[data-type="'+type+'"]').show(); 
});
```

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/z6ngr/

Answer (score 0):

Not very professional, but works.
***Javascript only.***

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

var col_1_items = new Array("Alex","Mark","John")


function editTable () {
    var  rows = col_1_items.length; //Or whatever like 1,2,3 ..
    var  cols = 1; //Each col should have its array of items !



    var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');

    //delete old rows

    for(var i = myTable.rows.length-2; i > -1; i--)
    {

    myTable.deleteRow(i);
    }

    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {

        var row = myTable.insertRow(r);
        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {

            var cell = row.insertCell(c);

            if (document.getElementById('filter').value == "All") {
                cell.innerHTML = col_1_items[r]
            }
            else {
                var indexOfFilterInArray = col_1_items.indexOf(document.getElementById('filter').value)
                cell.innerHTML = col_1_items[indexOfFilterInArray];
                myTable = null //Break the parent cycle that otherwise would go on adding rows.
                break;

            }


        }
    }
}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable" rules="all" border="1">
<tr><td colspan="2"> Filter<select id='filter'>
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="Alex">Alex</option>
</select>
<button onclick="editTable()">Go</button>
</td></tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```